# Authlogic:facebook connect - error undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I'm trying to integrate facebook connect to authlogic which is working fine with OAuth twitter. I get this error right after putting the button to the login form.

```
undefined local variable or method `authlogic_facebook_login_button'
```

Does anyone here know what the issue is? I already restarted the server after installing the plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! It was another silly mistake. I installed the plugin by executing this line on my Windows rad rails console.

```
script/plugin install http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect.git
```

Just now I noticed that the `/vendor/plugins/authlogic_facebook_connect` dir is empty. The issue is on windows there we need to pass a trailing slash to the end of URL to get the directory contents. So I ran this and restarted the server, and it works.

```
script/plugin install http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect.git/ --force
+ ./README.rdoc
+ ./init.rb
+ ./lib/authlogic_facebook_connect.rb
+ ./lib/authlogic_facebook_connect/acts_as_authentic.rb
+ ./lib/authlogic_facebook_connect/helper.rb
+ ./lib/authlogic_facebook_connect/session.rb
+ ./lib/authlogic_facebook_connect/version.rb
```